# How to toggle whitespace mode in evil insert state?

Tags: evil, whitespace-mode

I'd like to disable `whitespace-mode` while in evil  insert state. The following hooks work, but require refreshing all font colors with `(font-lock-fontify-buffer)`, and even then- sometimes it fails to refresh properly to show trailing whitespace.

While this example uses evil-mode, similar logic applies to any other hook.

```
(defun i42/enter-insert-mode ()
  (whitespace-mode -1)
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
(defun i42/exit-insert-mode ()
  (whitespace-mode 1)
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
(add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook 'i42/enter-insert-mode)
(add-hook 'evil-insert-state-exit-hook  'i42/exit-insert-mode)
```

Is there a better way to toggle white space mode?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want it on in insert state?

Comment: Does `redraw-display` or `redisplay` fix this issue? These functions should redraw the display and possibly fix your problem.

Comment: If you manually disable `whitespace-mode` without using `evil`, does the screen refresh properly without any extra steps?

Comment: @Dan, because I have a bright color set for trailing space which is distracting when entering text. Checked `redraw-display`, `redraw` & manually toggling `whitespace-mode` - none of them properly refresh the background color of trailing space, found a workaround, temporarily change the theme color - will post as a possible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround I'd found is to temporarily change the face background color.

```
;; Don't show trailing space in insert mode.
(defvar i42/whitespace-trailing-bg (face-attribute 'whitespace-trailing :background))
(defun i42/enter-insert-mode ()
  (set-face-attribute 'whitespace-trailing nil :background nil :foreground nil))
(defun i42/exit-insert-mode ()
  (set-face-attribute 'whitespace-trailing nil :background i42/whitespace-trailing-bg :foreground nil))

(add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook 'i42/enter-insert-mode)
(add-hook 'evil-insert-state-exit-hook  'i42/exit-insert-mode)
```