# How to get/read face attributes?

Tags: faces

The following Emacs Lisp you can set the background color of face `whitespace-trailing`:

```
(set-face-attribute 'whitespace-trailing nil :background "#ff0000" :foreground nil))
```

How can a face attribute be read back?

---

Asking since I'd like to temporarily change a face background color:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29166/2418

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `face-attribute`.

To match the example given, the following expression gets the trailing space background color:

```
(face-attribute 'whitespace-trailing :background)
```

> face-attribute is a compiled Lisp function in `faces.el'.
>
> (face-attribute FACE ATTRIBUTE &optional FRAME INHERIT)
>
> :around advice: `ad-Advice-face-attribute'
>
> Return the value of FACE's ATTRIBUTE on FRAME.
>   If the optional argument FRAME is given, report on face FACE in that frame.
>   If FRAME is t, report on the defaults for face FACE (for new frames).
>   If FRAME is omitted or nil, use the selected frame.
>
> If INHERIT is nil, only attributes directly defined by FACE are considered,
>     so the return value may be `unspecified`, or a relative value.
>   If INHERIT is non-nil, FACE's definition of ATTRIBUTE is merged with the
>     faces specified by its `:inherit` attribute; however the return value
>     may still be `unspecified` or relative.
>   If INHERIT is a face or a list of faces, then the result is further merged
>     with that face (or faces), until it becomes specified and absolute.
>
> To ensure that the return value is always specified and absolute, use a
>   value of `default` for INHERIT; this will resolve any unspecified or
>   relative values by merging with the `default` face (which is always
>   completely specified).